# passing structure directly to function

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct that I initialize like this:

```
typedef struct
{
 word w;
 long v;
}
MyStruct;


MyStruct sx = {0,0};
Update(sx);
```

Now, it seems such a waste to first declare it and then to pass it. I know that in C#, there's a way to do everything in one line. Is there any possiblity of passing it in a more clever (read: cleaner) way to my update function?

Comment: Why is it important to have everything on one line?  The compiler will generate the same code (removing unused instances).  Always use more than one line if the code is more readable.  Also, using more than one line may ease debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how your `Update` is declared. If it expects a value of `MyStruct` type or a reference of `const MyStruct&` type, you can just do

```
Update(MyStruct());
```

This is possible because you wanted to initialize your object with zeroes (which is what the `()` initializer will do in this case). If you needed different (non-zero) initializer values, you have to either provide a constructor for `MyStruct` or do it the way you do it in your question (at least in the current version of the C++ language).

Answer (score 6):

In C++, structs are the same as classes except in structs everything is public by default. So you can give a struct a constructor, e.g.

```
struct MyStruct
{
 word w;
 long v;

 MyStruct(word w, long v) : w(w), v(v) {}
};


Update(MyStruct(0,0));
```

Also, C-style struct typedef'ing is unnecessary and discouraged in C++.

Comment: +1 on using the constructor. The typedef in C++ actually makes a slight difference (from just naming the struct with the name) but in most cases it will be unnoticed and unimportant (and it is most probably not the reason why it was in the question's code)